# Inno Setup - How to silence a BASS Audio Library (music) in a particular page?

Tags: audio, inno-setup

How to silence a BASS Audio Library (music) in a particular page of my setup? (and continue the music before or after this page). Is it possible?

Comment: So do you want to mute (*"silence"*) or pause/resume (*"continue"*) the music? It's not clear from your wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the [`BASS_Pause`](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_Pause.html)/[`BASS_Start`](http://www.un4seen.com/doc/#bass/BASS_Start.html) from the [`CurPageChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurPageChanged):

The following example pauses the playback on the "Ready to Install" page.

```pascal
function BASS_Start: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Start@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Pause: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Pause@files:bass.dll stdcall';

var
  Paused: Boolean;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpReady then
  begin
    BASS_Pause;
    Paused := True;
  end
    else
  if Paused then
  begin
    BASS_Start;
    Paused := False;
  end;
end;
```